# getLastRow() "не корректно" работает на листе c arrayformula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

На листе данные формируются через ARRAYFORMULA, находящиеся в заголовках таблицы. Когда в GAS пытаюсь определить последнюю строку, используя getLastRow(), то последний выдает все количество строк на листе. Такое ощущение, что он считает их заполненными.
Как с эти бороться, чтобы можно было использовать getLastRow()? Или единственны вариант писать собственную МЕДЛЕННУЮ функцию по определению последнего ряда?

Comment: Зачем сразу - писать функцию,да еще и медленную? На листе вписать формулу для определения последней строки и возвращенное значение брать для последующих вычислений

Comment: vikttur подскажите такую формулу, пж.

Comment: Например, функция ПРОСМОТР. Если значения в столбце отсортированы, использовать МАКС или МИН. Еще вариант - ArrayFormula сцепки ЕСЛИ и МАКС

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ARRAYFORMULA` "растягивается" на весь указанный диапазон, т.о. весь диапазон становится используемым.

- `=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A100)` - `getLastRow` вернет сотый индекс;
- `=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A)` - `getLastRow` вернет последнюю строку Таблицы.

Это никак не обходится, `ARRAYFORMULA` - особенная формула.

Comment: Спасибо! Так я и думал.